# Visual Studio Performance Profiling .Net Core console application shows significant CPU usage by "unwalkable" calls into nvlddmkm.sys

Tags: c#, .net-core, profiling, visual-studio-2019

I have a .Net Core console application that is single-threaded and CPU bound, so I'm trying to optimize performance. When I run Visual Studio 2019's Performance Profiler and choose the "CPU usage" tool, I get what you see below.

Why is 22% of all CPU time spent in the "unwalkable" calls to `nvlddmkm.sys`?

[image: "Unwalkable" takes a significant portion of time]
[image: "Unwalkable" calls into <code>nvlddmkm.sys</code>]

Here's my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        const int length = 250;
        var array = new double[length];
        for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < length; ++j)
            {
                for (var k = 0; k < length; ++k)
                {
                    var index = i + j * k;
                    index %= length;
                    array[index] = random.NextDouble() + array[length - index - 1];
                    array[index] += array.Sum();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that calls into `nvlddmkm.sys` didn't happen (or at least didn't take as much time) without the Linq `Sum`.

I searched for what `nvlddmkm.sys` is. [This page](https://www.file.net/process/nvlddmkm.sys.html) says:

> Nvlddmkm.sys is a kernel mode driver for the Windows Longhorn project (a codename for Windows Vista) that adds support for shader models 3.0 and 2.0.

So what would Linq have to do with graphics?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, those stats are dumb. What you want to know is *which lines of your program* are responsible for the time, and those stats don't come near telling you. [*Here's how I do it.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)

OK, if I'm hazarding a guess (and the first rule of performance tuning is - *don't guess*), 
The `new double[]` call *might* show up as a major time-taker, because memory allocation is always suspect, but in this context I doubt it.
More likely, the `array.Sum()` call 
Most likely, the `random.NextDouble()` call
These last two happen 15,625,000 times.
Everything else in your program is pretty trivial.

Comment: The triviality and obviousness of `.Sum()` taking all the time and being the cause of the "unwalkable" calls into `nvlddmkm.sys`, while true, is not the point. In fact, I had to edit my question to get a better (read: more obvious and trivial) MCVE, and thus this toy example. I'm wondering "Why is 22% of all CPU time spent in the "unwalkable" calls _to nvlddmkm.sys_?" as in "So what would Linq have to do with graphics?" meaning why `nvlddmkm.sys`?

Answer (score 0):

Did the compiler optimize the code to use matrix operations on the GPU? That could explain the need to talk to a shader DLL.